# Show column from database in report footer of SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, footer, ssrs-2012

Is it possible to show data from database in SSRS footer?

I tried but the only option present is to show first record from dataset. But I want to show all records (I just need to show one column) one by one on each page.

Is it possible?

Comment: Have a hard time picturing what you mean.   Is the data you want in the footer related to the other data on the same page in some way?

Comment: Yes. I am showing Department report. So on each page some Department related data is shown. So I want my report to show Department name in footer based on current department it is showing. Other department related data will be shown in report body.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment I believe this link [Display on Page Footer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/08785944-923e-445a-b7de-b1062ea97879/absolutely-pagebottom-alignment-on-report-footer-impossible?forum=sqlreportingservices) is what you are looking for. 
I tried this and it works on Page Footer.

Comment: I am already doing this. What I want this to show data in report footer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by making your report a list of subreports.

Make a new report with a List item and a dataset that gets a set of all the departments you are going to get.  Consider this to be your "List" report.

Populate the list with the dataset.  Put a page break between List item members.

Make another report (or modify your existing one so) that is designed to be a single-page report about a single department, so @department will be one of the parameters.   It contains all the data you want on each page of your report, including the footer with the Department name, which it gets from the department parameter, so it doesn't need to get it from a dataset.   Consider this your "Base" report.

Going back to your List report, put a sub-report in your List item, point the sub-report to your Base report, and populate the department parameter with the value from the dataset that is populating the List.

Comment: I don't think subreport will work because you cannot show footer from sub report in main report plus you cannot pass any value from sub report to main report.

Comment: What do you mean by "show footer from sub report in main report"?   You won't have a footer in the main report.   The footer in the subreport will be the footer the user sees on every page.  I know my method works, because I've used it.  Unless you have some additional requirement that you haven't disclosed yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible using the "Lookup" aggregate function.

Assume, your report has a dataset named "Department_DataSet" which contains all the department's data plus one additional column e.g. PageNum, that contains an integer sequence starting from 1, giving you, basically, a sequence of the report page numbers:

```
PageNum | DepartmentName   |  Address   | etc.
--------+------------------+------------+-----
   1    | Department 1     |  ...       | ...
   2    | Department 2     |  ...       | ...
  ...
   N    | Department N     |  ...       | ...
```

Now, add a Textbox into the footer and assign the following expression to it:

```
=Lookup(Globals!PageNumber, Fields!PageNum.Value, Fields!DepartmentName.Value, "Department_DataSet")
```

and it will show the department name as required, but please ensure that the page numbers go in the same order as the departments in your detail report.

Comment: It won't work in my case because each department's info spans multiple pages which is not fixed. For e.g. Department 1 is being displayed on 2 pages while Department 2 is being displayed on 5 pages and Department 3 is being displayed on 1 page etc.

Comment: @Frank Martin, is it possible to calculate the number of pages required for each particular department?

Comment: No department count is dynamic